# Can I use a basic Web App in Azure to just define a SignalR hub with AZ SignalR Service and use other apps as clients to communicate between them

Tags: azure, service, connection, signalr

I have been struggling with this for few days so I am asking whether what I am trying to do is possible.

Basically I am experimenting things with signalR in Azure. I am using the latest version of SignalR NuGet.

I have a small Web App defining a simple signalR hub I want to access via a Azure SignalR Service.

I then have a couple of apps which communicate via hub in the signalR service.

I have various issues.

- Getting the hub to load on the AZ SignalR Service. It does not work all the time. Complaining about Serverless/Default settings...

```
2023-02-16T14:05:25.034917571Z info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
2023-02-16T14:05:25.034960072Z       Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://nmg-opus-common-inventory-dev-sigr.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=myhub&cid=9e64b380-b752-4175-8fd2-215a2b62139d'.
2023-02-16T14:05:25.057819457Z info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
2023-02-16T14:05:25.057859557Z       WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
2023-02-16T14:05:25.057865857Z info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
2023-02-16T14:05:25.057870457Z       Connection to service '(Primary)https://nmg-opus-common-inventory-dev-sigr.service.signalr.net(hub=MyHub)' handshake failed, probably caused by network instability or service restart. Will retry after the back off period. Error detail: Azure SignalR Service is in serverless mode, server connection is not allowed.. Id: 9e64b380-b752-4175-8fd2-215a2b62139d
2023-02-16T14:05:25.057875657Z info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[6]
2023-02-16T14:05:25.057880257Z       Transport is stopping.
2
```

- On the client side, it seems that the connection succeeds if the service is set to Serverless mode.
- Once connected, my call to join a group just hang and never returns. The connection happens after I click an element (div) on a blazor page.

So I am not sure why something so simple does not work.

here is my very simple hub :

```
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {

        public async Task SendMessage(string groupName, string message)
        {
            await Group(groupName).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }


        public async Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }

        public async Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
        {
            await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("Connected", Context.ConnectionId);
        }

    }
```

here is the classic startup method for the app defining hub

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
            services.AddSignalR(e => { e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10240000; });

            string SignalRURLHub = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Resources:SignalR:Inventory:ConnectionString");
            services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(SignalRURLHub);

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAzureAppConfiguration();
            app.UseRouting();

            var SignalRHubName = $"/{Configuration.GetValue<string>("Resources:SignalR:HubName")}";

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>(SignalRHubName);
            });
        }
    }
```

Code from the client applications Initializing the connection and starting it.

```
        protected HubConnection _connection;

        private readonly string groupName;

        protected ClientHandler(string connectionString, string hubName, string groupName, string userId = null)
        {
            var serviceUtils = new ServiceUtils(connectionString);

            var url = GetClientUrl(serviceUtils.Endpoint, hubName);
            _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(url
                , option =>
                {
                    option.AccessTokenProvider = () =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(serviceUtils.GenerateAccessToken(url, userId));
                    };
                })
                
                .WithAutomaticReconnect(new AlwaysRetryPolicy())
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                    logging.AddConsole();
                })
                .Build();
                
           this.groupName = groupName;
           _connection.Reconnected += JoinGroup;
           _connection.On("Connected", new[] { typeof(string) }, OnInitialConnection);
        }


        private string GetClientUrl(string endpoint, string hubName)
        {
            return $"{endpoint}/client/?hub={hubName}";
        }

        private async Task JoinGroup(string contextId)
        {
            try
            {
                await _connection.InvokeAsync("JoinGroup", groupName);  //JoinGroup is C# method name
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }


        // Called separately after the ClientHandler object is created.

        public async Task StartAsyncWithRetry(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                     await _connection.StartAsync()
                        .ContinueWith(res =>
                    {
                        _connection.InvokeAsync("JoinGroup", groupName);
                    });

                    if (_connection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(GetRandomDelayMilliseconds());
                        continue;
                    }

                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //throw;

                    //cancellationToken.
                    await Task.Delay(GetRandomDelayMilliseconds());
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried tweaking various setting in Azure, in my apps, changed my code from synch to async...

I must be missing something ... I've found lot of post but many of them were out of date. Also tried my luck with ChatGPT ...